# {"SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: Products'."}

Tags: sqlite, mvvm, entity-framework-6, .net-6.0

I am getting this error {"SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: Products'."} on the second catch.

This is my Dbcontext

```
public class MarcodtDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductType> Producttypes { get; set; }

    public MarcodtDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>(entity =>
        {
            //Primany Key Code configuration
            entity.HasKey(c => c.Code);

            entity.Property(c => c.Code)
                  .HasMaxLength(30);


            //Name attribute configuration
            entity.Property(n => n.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(255);


            //Uom attribute configuration
            entity.Property(u => u.Uom)
           .IsRequired()
           .HasMaxLength(30);

            entity.HasOne<ProductType>(p => p.PType)
            .WithMany(p => p.Products)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.Type)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);

        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProductType>(entity =>
        {
            //Primany Key Type configuration
            entity.HasKey(t => t.Type);

            entity.Property(t => t.Type).ValueGeneratedNever();

            //Name attribute configuration
            entity.Property(n => n.Name).HasMaxLength(255);
        });
    }
}
```

I am following a tutorial and customising the code to my idea.
How can I see the tables in my database and troubleshoot this error?

Comment: What tutorial are you following? You can see tables with https://sqlitebrowser.org/

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a silly one, but I will keep the question in case this could be useful to anyone.

Make sure you do an `add-migration <migration name>` in the package manager console before running the program.